# inserting c++ code in java

Tags: java, c++

Is there a way to insert some c++ code in java ?

for some reason my code which is:

```
    ArRobotPacket pkt;
    pkt.setID(ArCommands::SIM_SET_POSE);
    pkt.uByteToBuf(0); // argument type: ignored.
    pkt.byte4ToBuf(x);
    pkt.byte4ToBuf(y);
    pkt.byte4ToBuf(th);
    pkt.finalizePacket();
    robot.getDeviceConnection()->write(pkt.getBuf(), pkt.getLength());
```

translated to java, will not function, the write will actually send a packet but doesn't effect the program the way it should

This code is from 
http://robots.mobilerobots.com/MobileSim/download/current/README.html#mapobjs

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Java Native Interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/